# Wifi problem (Lenovo A850+)

Tags: wi-fi, lenovo

The phone wifi seem like blocking the internet after the wifi idle for few second. Then I have to disconnect and reconnect the phone wifi. I think it is related to wifi power saving mode or Wifi Sleep Policy. Any suggestion would be great. **Thanks**

Comment: Hi Nick, welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Pls feel free to [take the tour](http://android.stackexchange.com/tour). I can't quite understand what you're asking here - are you saying wifi _pretty much never_ works unless you turn it off and back on again?

Comment: Yes, I have to reconnect the wifi after a few second the wifi idle. I think it has to do with Wifi Sleep Policy which it failed to awake from idle state. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, the problem solved. I've changed the wifi router setting. Changed **Preamble Type** from Long to Short. Then restart wifi router. Doing this wont last forever, I have to restart the wifi router once a day.